# Using same php files with include erease the main page

Tags: php, html, sql, include

everyone. The deal is I'm trying to do an overflow-x=scroll show for products in a company and show productos there using a database with php. Everything was fine, I pack the code of it in an eternal php file and try to use it twice with include. The main idea is to only chance the sql of the second include and respective querySelect file to avoid writing the code twice. The PROBLEM is that when I include the 2 files the first one content doesnt show neither the second one and everything that's after it. The code is something like:

```
<div>Div with some content<div>
<?php require ("productos.php"); ?>
<div>Div with some content<div>
<?php require ("productos1.php"); ?>/*This file will be the same as the other but with different sql*/
<div>Guest what? More divs<div>
```

What does the php file has? Well it's:

```
  <?php

    require "querySelect.php";

    $productos = new columnas();

    $array_productos = $productos->get_items();

    foreach ($array_productos as $value) {

      echo
      '<div class="card">
        <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-nombre="' . $value["NOMBRE"] . '" data-imagen="' . $value["IMAGEN"] . '" data-color="' . $value["COLOR"] . '" data-peso="' . $value["PESO"] . '" data-tiempo="' . $value["TIEMPO"] . '" data-observaciones="' . $value["OBSERVACIONES"] . '" class="card-img-top" src="' . $value["IMAGEN"] . '" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block p-3">
          <h4 class="card-title">' . $value["NOMBRE"] . '</h4>
          <p class="card-text">' . $value["DESCRIPCION"] . '</p>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>';
    }
  ?>
```

The querySelect.php is:

```
<?php

  require "conexion.php";

  class columnas extends conexion {

    public function columnas() {

      parent::__construct();

    }

    public function get_items() {

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM primaproductos";

      $sentencia = $this->conexion_db->prepare($sql);

      $sentencia->execute(array());

      $resultados = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $sentencia->closeCursor();

      return $resultados;

      $this->conexion_db = null;


      /*$resultados = $this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM post');

      $productos = $resultados->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      return $resultados;*/
    }

  }

?>
```

Last file:

```
<?php

  require "config.php";

  class conexion {

    protected $conexion_db;

    public function conexion() {

      //--------------PDO-------------------------------------------------------------------

      try {

        $this->conexion_db = new PDO('mysql:host=###; dbname=###', '###', '###');

        $this->conexion_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $this->conexion_db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

        return $this->conexion_db;

      } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "La linea de error es: " . $e->getLine();
      }

  }

?>
```

Comment: If you're trying to avoid writing code twice, requiring a separate file (which in itself requires two more files) seems a bit overkill. You'd be better off just piping coditional logic to your SQL statement :)

Comment: Change all your `require` to `require_once`. And turn on php error reporting, so you can avoid asking questions about simple syntax issues.

Comment: @IncredibleHat thanks you, I active error reporting, I'm nearly completely new in php (and everything related), a use the descripcion to find similiar problems. The problem was that I was calling twice querySelect.php and of course I created 2 times the same class

Comment: @adrianwixtorres yup, multiple include/require calls to the same file can cause some pretty wonky issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Files : [ Conexion.php , ( querySelect.php check the return statement.. ) ] i suppose are okay.

I think you're using bootstrap 4, so you should have a good structure before, i mean..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
        <!-- HERE THE CARD ELEMENT, so 
          http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php
        -->
       <?php require_once('productos.php'); ?>
       <!-- And div with class col-12 or whatever you want per item -->
  </div>
</div>
```

## Productos.php

I think your mistake gonna be here too i mean..

Check elements before..

```
if ( !empty($array_productos) ) {
 //The foreach
 foreach ($array_productos as $value) {
   echo '<div class="col-12">'.$value["nombre"].PHP_EOL.'</div>';
 }
};
```

I hope this help to you =)